# Applescript - Download Script

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite, download

I've made this download script a few days ago:

```
do shell script "curl -L -o ~/Desktop/file.dmg 'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-27.0.1-SSL&os=osx&lang=en-GB' > ~/Desktop/status 2>&1 &"
set fileSize to 0
set curTransferred to 0
set curProgress to 0
repeat until curProgress = "100"
    try
        set lastLine to paragraph -1 of (do shell script "cat ~/Desktop/status")
        set curProgress to word 1 of lastLine
        set fileSize to word 2 of lastLine
        set curTransferred to word 4 of lastLine
        tell me
            display dialog "Downloading. Please wait...

Status: " & curTransferred & " of " & fileSize & " (" & curProgress & "%)" buttons {"Refresh", "cancel"} giving up after 4
            if the button returned of the result is "cancel" then return
        end tell
    on error
        display dialog "Something went wrong when downloading the file. If you would like to restart the download then press the button 'Retry'" buttons {"Quit", "Retry"} with icon 0
    end try
end repeat
```

It works, but I still have got some problems (3 to be exact)
Problem number one:

Is there a way to display ONLY the CurTransferred, FileSize and Curprogress without making a new window every 4 seconds to display/refresh the (new) information?

Problem number two:

Is there a way in applescript to make a kind of 'Pause' button (in this script)? So when clicking pause the download will stop and a new dialog will open with a 'Continue' or 'Start' button?

Problem number three:

Is there a way to change the `~/Desktop/file.dmg` to a code like this one:
`set downloadlocation to (choose folder)` and then something like: `path to (downloadlocation)` in the script instead of `~/Desktop/file.dmg`

If you know an answer to one of the problems (or all) then don't hesitate to answer this question(s)!

Thanks for reading,

Jort

PS: maybe also a check for Internet Connection would be cool but not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem number one:

No

Problem number two:

No

Problem number three

```
set downloadLocation to choose folder with prompt "choose download location"
do shell script "curl -L -o " & quoted form of (POSIX path of downloadLocation & "file.dmg") & " 'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-27.0.1-SSL&os=osx&lang=en-GB' > ~/Desktop/status 2>&1 &"
```

Problems one and two are not solvable with pure AppleScript because AS works synchronously in a single thread. As the shell script is set not to wait for completion, there is no way to control the progress except to read the output from the status file.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your quick answer :) and also the explanation why one and two are not possible is very helpful.